# Interacting with a program running as part of a systemd service

Tags: command-line-interface, service, systemd, terminal, stream

I've got a systemd service set up with the following configuration (in `/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/service
User=some-user
Group=some-group
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=20 5
ExecStart=my-service-binary

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the program is started, it provides a command line interface to allow interaction. However, as this program is run by systemd, I can't immediately see a way to interact with the program directly. Is there some way to "connect" to the stream the program provides, while running it as a service within systemd?

Comment: Have a chat with the program's developers about a more reasonable method of interacting with the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `man systemd.exec`, you'll find that you can set `StandardInput=` to a value of `tty`, and then set `TTYPath=` to set a particularly TTY to connect to.

It's fairly unconventional to use `systemd` to run CLI apps though.

Some services may *appear* to run via `systemd` and offer a CLI, but they are really using a client/server model. For example, database servers are typically run via `systemd`, but you connect to them via CLI when they are running.

How the client/server interaction works is specific to each server. Usually they are communicating over a local port or socket.

You should first confirm if the *service* you running is designed to connect directly to a TTY or whether it actually listening a local port or socket that a CLI-based client connects to.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a try and see if I can get it to work. I'm unfamiliar with how TTY works so I'll first have to look at that.